# Python 3 - Copy a block of text from an ASCII file

Tags: python-3.x

I want to copy a block of text from an ASCII file.

For example, from line:

```
*ELEMENT, TYPE=S3, ELSET=DAM
```

till the line:

```
*ELEMENT, TYPE=S4, ELSET=WALL
```

, and then write it in a new ASCII file.

Could you explain me how?

```
...
*NODE, NSET=NEW
1,  3., 4., 5.
2,  6., 1., 4.
1,  3., 4., 5.
2,  6., 1., 4.
*ELEMENT, TYPE=S3, ELSET=DAM
1,  1,  2,  3
2,  4,  5,  6
...
*ELEMENT, TYPE=S4, ELSET=WALL
11, 10, 20, 30
25, 40, 50, 60
...
```

Answer (score 1):

open the file, read until you get to the start line, write that line then use an inner loop until you hit the end line then end the function:

```
def get_section(in_f, out_f, start, end):
    with open(in_f) as f, open(out_f,"w") as out:
        for line in f:
            if line.strip() == start:
                out.write(line)
                for line in f:
                    if line.strip() == end:
                        out.write(line)
                        return
                    out.write(line)
get_section("in.txt","out.txt","*ELEMENT, TYPE=S3, ELSET=DAM","*ELEMENT, TYPE=S4, ELSET=WALL")
```

Comment: Hi Padraic, I have slightly modified your code to read only *NODE block. From *NODE till *ELEMENT. But it can not catch the block.

Comment: def block(in_f, out_f, start, end):
    with open(in_f) as f, open(out_f,"w") as out:
        for line in f:
            word=line.split(',')
            if word[0] == start:
                out.write(line)
                for line in f:
                    if word[0] == end: return
                    out.write(line)
block("in.txt","out.txt","*NODE","*ELEMENT")

Comment: That is because word never changes. You never split in the inner loop

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi all
Well my initial question was incomplete. 
In fact my objectif is to find out some given 
block of text having a given pattern. In example 
below, I try to get all blocks starting with *ELEMENT 
till the line starting with *ANYTHING
...
** I am a comment
*NODE
1,  3., 4., 5.
2,  6., 1., 4.
1,  3., 4., 5.
2,  6., 1., 4.

*ELEMENT, TYPE   =   S3,            ELSET=DAM
1,  1,  2,  3
2,  4,  5,  6
*NODE
10,  3., 4., 5.
20,  6., 1., 4.
*ELEMENT, TYPE=S4, ELSET=WALL
11, 10, 20, 30
25, 40, 50, 60
*NODE, NSET         =SOMETHING_ELSE
100,  3., 4., 5.
*ELEMENT          , TYPE   =   S4, ELSET=WALL2
11, 10, 20, 30
25, 40, 50, 60
...

Finally I have modified the code from Padraic as following 
to get blocks from randomly written input deck. It may 
interest at least FEM engineers so here it is. 
If you have a more elegent solution I will appreciate it.
```

```
def parse_command(in_f, out_f, command):
    with open(in_f) as f, open(out_f,"a") as out:
        lines = f.readlines();
        file_list=[]
        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith('**') or not line.strip() :
                continue
            else:
                line = ' '.join(line.split())
                line = line.replace('= ','=')
                file_list.append(line+'\n')
#
        for i in range (len(file_list)):
            str=file_list[i]
            if (str.startswith(command)):
               out.write(str)
               for j in range (i+1,len(file_list)):
                   str=file_list[j]
                   if (str[0].isdigit() or str[0].isalpha()):
                       out.write(str)
                   if (str.startswith('*')):
                       break
    return

parse_command('in.txt','out.txt', '*ELEMENT' )
```